# what is the difference between allocated and reserved memory?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, stack

as a beginner in learning embedded softwares ,I can not understand the **nuance between reserved memory and allocated memory** , can anybody help me ?

Comment: There's no such thing as reserved memory in C or C++. Can you give an example of what you're referring to?

Comment: This might refer to "statically allocated" versus "dynamically allocated". The phrasing you're using is unconventional. Is this something a C++ "professor" is going on about? They often invent their own highly idiosyncratic terms.

Comment: I'm trying to learn from an online course which there is this paragraph :" _Stack is automatically used by the compiler, which in turn utilized architecture-specific processes and instructions to call and return from a routine. All of these operations get compiled into the function call. There's still overhead, in order to call and return from a function, and the memory region of the stack occupies part of data memory. **This is reserved at compile time, allocated at run time**, and the operations to interact with this region are introduced at compilation.

Comment: Your reference text appears to be describing certain aspects of the code generated by your 'cross' compiler for your embedded system.  Topic to investigate:  bsp (board support package).  "A board support package (BSP) is essential code code for a given computer hardware device that will make that device work with the computer's OS (operating system). The BSP contains a small program called a boot loader or boot manager that places the OS and device drivers into memory"   BSP issues are probably NOT C++ syntax issues.  The bsp's I have seen are mixes of assy, c, and c++.

Comment: @Barmar: There is such a thing as reserved memory in C. It is the storage that has been provided for an object—any object. For example, C 2018 6.2.4 2 says “The *lifetime* of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it…”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your quoted paragraph, they are only talking about the call stack (which is one of the possible types of memory).

The call-stack has a maximum size that is "reserved" at compile time, but it is mostly unused when the program starts.  Your local variables and function calls get pushed onto the stack when you make a function call -- that temporarily "allocates" memory until the function returns -- then it is "deallocated".

If you allocate more memory than you reserved -- for example with an infinite recursion, then your program will have a .......

Stack Overflow Error.